# QT Qvector<Class With Some Qvectors> , Memory Leak

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qvector

I have a class like this :

```
class temp_class
{
  public:
  QVector<double> a,b,c,d;
  temp_class() {
    for (int var = 0; var < 10000; ++var) {
        a.append(var);
        b.append(var);
        c.append(var);
        d.append(var);
    }
  }
  ~temp_class()
  {
    a.clear();
    b.clear();
    c.clear();
    d.clear();
  }
};
```

and i have qvector of pointers of this class like this:

```
QVector<temp_class*> temp_list;
```

and i append some class to it

```
for (int var = 0; var < 1e3; ++var) {
    temp_class * temp = new temp_class;
    temp_list.append(temp);
}
```

but when i clear this vector memory do not cleanup !!!!!

```
qDeleteAll(temp_list);
temp_list.clear();
```

why this weird event happens?!!!!

OS : Ubuntu 14.04.3

QT 4.8.6

Comment: What's your proof that "memory do not cleanup"?

Comment: ubuntu "System Monitor" application show that, if i do that more times ,system memory resource end and ubuntu will hang .....

Comment: Could this be cause by memory fragmentation? (bold guess) Can you try using `QVector::reserve(10000)` in your constructor to prevent multiple reallocation when calling `append` and see if its change the behavior?

Comment: i tried that , same as before !!!!!!